# Redis: SET command when data starts with a newline character

Tags: c, redis

I'm using Redis in a C program I'm writing (with hiredis C binding).

Here is my code:

```
void insert(redisContext* c,char* buf){
        static redisReply *reply;
        const char* hash="asdf";
        char* cmd=(char*)malloc((strlen("SET ")+strlen(hash)+strlen(" ")+CHUNKSIZE)*sizeof(char));

        //hash=getHash(buf);
        memcpy(cmd,"SET ",(size_t)strlen("SET "));
        memcpy(cmd+strlen("SET "),hash,(size_t)strlen(hash));
        memcpy(cmd+strlen("SET ")+strlen(hash)," ",(size_t)strlen(" "));
        memcpy(cmd+strlen("SET ")+strlen(hash)+strlen(" "),buf,(size_t)CHUNKSIZE);

        fwrite(cmd,strlen("SET ")+strlen(hash)+strlen(" ")+CHUNKSIZE,sizeof(char),stdout);
        printf("\n\n\n\n\n\n");
        reply=(redisReply*)redisCommand(c,cmd);
        freeReplyObject(reply);

        free(cmd);
}
```

As you can see, the cmd looks like: `SET asdf xxx`, where xxx is 512 bytes long (binary data).

The problem arises when the binary data string begins with '\n'. I keep getting an error (segmentation fault).

Anyone have any ideas?

Many thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using the code you posted and didn't get any crash.
My code is:

```
#define CHUNKSIZE 512
char asd[CHUNKSIZE];
memset(asd, 0, 512);
asd[0] = '\n';
insert(c, asd);
```

Try running your app with `valgrind` that will probably give you a better idea of what's wrong before it crashes.

Comment: Thanks very much for the feedback. It's obviously some other error. Much appreciated,

Answer (score 1):

hiredis docs:

> When you need to pass binary safe strings in a command, the %b specifier can be used. Together with a pointer to the string, it requires a size_t length argument of the string:

```
reply = redisCommand(context, "SET foo %b", value, valuelen);
```